# I can't connect via SSH in my compute engine (web)

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

Since last week I can't log into my virtual machine via SSH (via web). Already increased the disk space, increased RAM, already created a new SSH and includes in metadata, nothing worked ...

When I try to connect to my local machine, I get this message:

> Permission denied (publickey). 
>   ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Could not SSH to the instance. It is possible that your SSH key has not
>   propagated to the instance yet. Try running this command again. If you
>   still cannot connect, verify that the firewall and instance are set to
>   accept ssh traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the path of the private key when you run the SSH command:

ssh -i [PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY] [USERNAME]@[EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS]

Here is how to locate the key [1].

For more information on how to troubleshoot this kind of issues [2].

Maybe the instance has OS Login enabled and it disables metadata-based SSH key configurations on those instances [3].

__

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#locatesshkeys

[2] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced

[3] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#enable_oslogin